# Advice on migrating a web app source code from Coffeescript to javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I've inherited responsibility for a moderately complex Rails app, which has meant learning Ruby and Rails besides trying to understand a lot of code that I did not write myself. The project also contains a non-trivial Backbone.js app written in Coffeescript. Since I will be the sole developer on this project for a long time, and since I don't know Coffeescript, I plan to move the entire source code to straight Javascript.

I would like to know what the best approach to doing this would be. Compiling to javascript is easy enough, but there is a lot of refactoring to do to make the code look "normal".

Cleaning up cruft by replacing stuff like

```
var a;
a = 1;
```

with

```
var a = 1;
```

is simple enough, or perhaps not even worth bothering with. I am more worried about the overall structure of the project. Coffeescript produces files that begin like this Backbone view code:

```
(function() {
  var extend = function(child, parent) {
    for (var key in parent)           {
        if (hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key];
  } function ctor() {
        this.constructor = child;
      }
    ctor.prototype = parent.prototype;
    child.prototype = new ctor();
    child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child;
  },
           hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty;

App.Views.MyClass = (function(superClass) {
extend(MyClass, superClass);

function MyClass() {
  return MyClass.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}
# rest of the code here...

    });
}).call(this);
```

I would just like to know what a sane approach to dealing with this would be, and I haven't found any kind of "best practices" for doing what I would like to do.

What would be best:  just check everything into git and keep going? Use the Backbone/Underscore version of `extend` instead of redefining the same function at the top of every file? Use a different method entirely for stringing together all of the separate files?

Just looking for a general direction. I'll figure out the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a tool like [decaffeinate](https://github.com/eventualbuddha/decaffeinate) if you are ok with using ES6.

Otherwise, if you are sure you want to port to Javascript, then you'd be better rewriting by hand, than trying to fix the generated code.

Start by recreating the files one at a time, writing unit tests as you go. Not only will this help you better understand the project, but you'll also learn Coffeescript (and probably some good techniques as you go).

If you read the [overview](http://coffeescript.org/) on the Coffeescript website, it provides a translation table for going between the two languages. Every time you come across syntax you don't understand, see what it generates when you enter it into [js2.coffee](http://js2.coffee/). There's another good reference for migrating from Coffeescript to ES6 [here](https://gist.github.com/danielgtaylor/0b60c2ed1f069f118562).

Comment: Unfortunately, ES6 won't be an option in my case. You and @AlphaG33k  have convinced me that I'm going down the wrong path with this. Especially since you say that I'll end up learning CoffeeScript anyway, I might as well bite the bullet now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Coffeescript's not that different from Javascript, if it helps. The changes are purely syntactic, most of the ideas will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

You will end up spending more time and much more effort (not to mention most likely introduce bugs trying to replicate things like super or sub-classes in CoffeeScript). Instead of trying to rewrite a working CoffeeScript web app, just dig in and soak up the CoffeeScript as you go along and find the need to change things. Stop resisting! CoffeeScript is well documented and has proven itself as a very useful language to know. Learn it, its only scary because its new!

Comment: I actually enjoy learning new languages. I've been resisting with CoffeeScript because 1) JS + Backbone is the only part of this project that uses something I know fairly well and 2) I've always felt that learning CoffeeScript wasn't worth it since in the end, it's still just... JavaScript. Thanks for your perspective on this, though, because with what you and @DanPrince have said, I'm starting to realize that what I wanted to do may indeed be a lose-lose proposition: lose time and lose code value...